# lty and lwd in standard R 3.02 not working?

Tags: r, data-visualization

I don't not know what I am doing wrong. This is sooo simple, but nevertheless I have no idea where my mistake is:

I have the following code:

```
x<-seq(-3000,3000,length=1000)
hx<-dnorm(x,mean=0,sd=1392.857)

plot(x,hx,lwd=3,lty=4,col="blue")
```

Which gives

[image: t1]

Then I code:

```
plot(x,hx,lwd=3,lty=1,col="blue")
```

And I get the same picture?

Why is lty not working here? Same holds for lwd? R somehow does not recognize it?

I had never a problem like this. I just downloaded the new R version, because my old crashed. Where is my mistake?

EDIT:
How can I get a thinner line? If I use lwd=1 it is still so fat (only a slight change)? R lines used to be very thin, normally I had to adjust lwd up? How can I get a thinner line?

Comment: Because this is about how to do something in R rather than statistics, this post will likely be off-topic. Please consult the CV Help Center for a description of CV's scope.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default of the `plot` function is to plot points, not lines. You created a plot with numerous points. Because they are so close to each other, the points appear like a single line. Hence, the arguments `lwd` and `lty` are ignored.

You have specify what `type` of plot should be drawn.

```
plot(x, hx, lwd = 3, lty = 4, col = "blue", type = "l")
```

The argument `type = "l"` is used to draw a line plot.

[image]